# click do not detect body in jquery

Tags: jquery, search, onclick

I am working in [website](http://cstland.com). I want to open the search after click on it's icon. I want to close it after clicking in any where except is icon. I am try closing in clicking on body but don't work.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: please post your code.